# I am Unable to use Alt + Enter in my Android Studio for Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart, alt

Also not able to See Intensions in setting

Ctrl+Alt+S for Setting in Android Studio but Intension is not Visible[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPN0z.png)

Comment: if your are looking for alt+enter it is `show context actions`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to

> File -> Settings -> Editor -> Intentions and Search the Dart Analysis
> Server and check it.

Apply & It's done!